# How to retrieve pair of columns from a DataTable as a Dictionary 

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a datatable that contains simple Key Value pair how do I return a dictionary object `(DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var dict = DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(
                r => r.Field<string>("KeyColumn"), 
                r => r.Field<DateTime>("ValueColumn")
);
```